# Can't send a FAX to one specific number

Tags: fax

We have a Canon MX470 printer here with integrated FAX.

We can send FAXes to all our customers expect one.

The problem is that our printer does not recognize when the destination FAX device picks up the call.

Our device remains in "Calling..." state.

We have VoIP.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Digital connections are not fax-friendly. ADSL kind of gets away with it sometimes but cable really hates it. Maybe they have a cable connection? Suggest email instead & see what they say.

Comment: @Tetsujin is correct. That faxing works on modern systems is more of a happy accident than something you can count on reliably. The problem exists in the connections and the incompatibilities introduced by them.

Comment: @Tetsujin: If the FAX is transferred via VoIP the kind of internet connection is regardless. You are talking about analogous telephony when having ADSL.

Comment: Incorrect - what happens is you are transmitting an analog signal via a digitised transmission method. The aliasing in the conversion is what breaks up the signal. VOIP is digital, whatever it travels over. ADSL, because it is already a digital over analog protocol just seems to not break it quite so badly as cable. If it works at all, it's a matter of luck. FAX was designed to work over a pure analog domain, something that is getting very rare these days.

Comment: This is basically an advert for a service, but not a recommendation. It has a good explanation of why it can fail over VOIP though - https://www.faxburner.com/blog/will-fax-machines-work-with-voip/

Comment: @Tetsujin Don't tell me how VoIP works! I studied this! VoIP is transferred via TCP or UDP IP packets! If you say that these IP packets are not well transferred then you are saying that ALL UDP packets are not well transferred via ADSL/cable (because TCP has error correction). I won't reply to any further comments.

Comment: I didn't say that at all. Anyway, we don't need the attitude. Voting to close.